# SPH example codes for solving differential equations

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, sph

I'm quite new to the smoothed particle hydrodynamics method, so I'm trying to find Matlab or Python code to help me understand it. Specifically, I want to know how to solve the one-dimensional diffusion equation like in this [paper](https://doi.org/10.9790/1684-115196101),

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \lambda \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$

SPH is reviewed in many good introductory texts, eg. [Monaghan](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0034-4885/68/8/R01) and [Price](https://users.monash.edu.au/%7Edprice/SPH/) papers. I understand the math/theory, but I'm trying to find a detailed simple code to see how things work numerically. I know there are software packages like [DualSPHysics](https://github.com/DualSPHysics/DualSPHysics), but I prefer something basic for solving the above differential equation. Can you please help?